# Is it safe to use print() with dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it safe to still use print() in dart (flutter 2.5.1), if not what command should I use to print errors?

```
  if (query != null) {
        _query.addAll(query);
      }
      return await dio.get(_url, queryParameters: _query);
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print('DioError:$e');
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are getting is just a warning. You should `throw` errors instead of printing it.

```
  if (query != null) {
        _query.addAll(query);
      }
      return await dio.get(_url, queryParameters: _query);
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're inside a widget ,

Use `debugPrint('data')` , because it'll only show data in **debug** mode and will not run in release mode. So, it'll save you a lot of time.

Otherwise , you can also use `log('data')` , it'll show whole **response** in logging pattern in console.